How to rebase a branch while keeping already merged commits?
We have the usual workflow of main, dev, and changes done in topic branches.
Sometimes we want to deploy a quick-fix to production but without merging other dev changes. We might do a PR and merge into dev (PR into main is not an option), then we'll require more changes in that branch.
Eventually, we need to keep the topic branch up-to-date with dev. Doing a merge from dev to topic is not ideal since we don't want to include dev changes when merging topic into main. We opt for a rebase in these cases.
However, when rebasing, the commits that were already merged into dev in a previous PR are omited, so when we want to cherry-pick a branch into main, only the non-merged commits would be included.
I wanted to know if there's a git command or set of flags/options that would allow me to rebase topic into dev but keeping the already merged commits (which would be empty in theory) so that when cherry-picking into main, all commits from the branch will be present with their respective changes into main.
This is what it looks like:
STARTING STATE
  dev branch   A - B - C - E - F - G
                     \
topic branch           H - I - J


AFTER PR MERGE
  dev branch   A - B - C - E - F - G - K - L   (K is merge commit, contains H and I changes)
                     \               /
topic branch           H - I - - - - - J


NORMAL REBASE
  dev branch   A - B - C - E - F - G - K - L   (Only J since H and I are already merged on K)
                                            \
topic branch                                 J


DESIRED OUTCOME AFTER REBASE
  dev branch   A - B - C - E - F - G - K - L   (H' and I' would be empty commits)
                                            \
topic branch                                 H' - I' - J


IN CASE WE WANT TO CHERRY-PICK TOPIC BRANCH INTO MAIN (MERGE ONLY TOPIC CHANGES)
  dev branch   G - K - L (H and I are cherry-picked from topic but contain the full changes)
                         \
topic branch               H' - I' - J

 main branch   - - - - - - - - - - - M - N - H - I - J - O

I couldn't find an option in Git's documentation that would do quite the thing I'm looking for. I've tried several settings to no avail.

The thing you want (empty H' and I' commits) is unnatural in Git terms. You cannot have it out of the box. To me, this looks like a strange thing to desire.

Assuming H, I are the quick-fix. Then the correct way to handle it is to branch it off of main rather than dev, ideally from the commit that introduced the problem that is being fixed by H and I. Then you can merge the quick-fix into any branch that has that problematic commit.

“Eventually, we need to keep the topic branch up-to-date with dev. Doing a merge from dev to topic is not ideal since we don't want to include dev changes when merging topic into main. We opt for a rebase in these cases.” If you start from dev then merging dev into the topic branch doesn’t introduce anything extra (that is not on dev).

git rebase --empty=keep. But probably do what @j6t already suggested.
